# Why am I getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" when trying to use Rollup with commonjs?

Tags: javascript, rollup, rollupjs

I have the [a project](https://github.com/jrgleason/rollup-demo/tree/develop/modules/simple-rollup) I am working on for fun to get UMD, ESM, and CommonJS examples working with rollup. The UMD and ESM ones work great but for the CommonJS one I am getting...

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

The CommonJS output is...

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

class SimpleTest{
    constructor(message){
        console.log(`Your message is ${message}`);
    }
}

exports.SimpleTest = SimpleTest;
```

The HTML is...

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/comments/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require(["./target/ng-demo.js"], (dep)=>{
        new dep.SimpleTest("ESM");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Wouldn't exports come from RequireJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to demonstrate `amd` instead of `cjs`. It doesn't make sense to run `cjs` on browser since it only works on node env.

You're trying to include `require.js` which supports `amd` on the browser, so you just simply switch your `cjs` to `amd` then it would work:

```
{
  file: "./target/ng-demo.js",
  format: "amd" // instead of `cjs`
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is the answer. Just out of curiosity how would I consume a commonjs file in the browser?

Comment: Nope. Cjs is designed for node only

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by setting the `module` compiler option to `es6`:

```
  {
  "compilerOptions": {     
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",    
  }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Actually sorry this doesn't work because it causes the ESM to become ES5 too thanks though

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested here is what I did to get CJS working...

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/require1k@2.0.0/require1k.min.js"></script>
<script>

    R(function (require, module, exports) {
        const {SimpleTest} = require("./target/ng-demo.cjs");
        new SimpleTest("commonjs");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```